# Git for CI (read only repository)

Tags: git

I have a cloned repository I use only for building some programs. After each build, there are some files added to the directory where the repository was cloned, hence, when I want to do a git pull, I get errors like these:

```
error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: please commit or stash them.
```

Then, I have to do a `git add .` then `git commit -m "commit before pull"` and `git pull`.

What can I do to work with this clone similarly as `subversion`, I mean, just pull from server and build, nothing more.

Comment: If you don't care about the local changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files

Comment: Yes, that seems like cloning the whole repository every time I need to do a build. The way this repo is created (many directories and files) it will take ~2 minutes for every fetch...Isn't there another way?